# Which Morrow Days signed the document?

Tags: keys-to-the-kingdom

In Garth Nix's Keys to the Kingdom series we find this passage:

> "I like not these legal niceties," grumbled Grim Tuesday. He pulled at his chin with a metal-bound hand, almost talking to himself. "What is done once to the Lower House might be done again to me and my realm. Besides, I see the seals of only three of the Morrow Days upon this document..."
>
> "You need only set your own seal there, and it will be four of seven. A majority, and the Lower House is yours.

Can we figure out which Morrow Days signed the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough to guess. It wasn't Arthur or Dame Primus, since they were the opposing party in the case. Lord Sunday is afflicted with the sin of Pride, and is well-known to be isolated in his gardens, with Superior Saturday in charge of the running of the House. At this point he's not too concerned with Arthur. (Pride, remember?) Drowned Wednesday is  a whale and spends most of her time eating. Although it would be theoretically possible to get her signature, it would be difficult. Further, she isn't hostile to Arthur.

Therefore, by process of elimination, Superior Saturday, Sir Thursday, and Lady Friday signed the document. Saturday is highly active in House affairs, as is Thursday. Although Friday is obsessed with experiencing the sensations of mortal life, she's not wholly disengaged.